# How to ignore spaces and blank lines in java

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner, readfile, bluej

and Also because my data contains spaces after or before the comma so I have used a regular expression to brake up the data, So how can I ignore the spaces and how can i break up the data so I can assign them to fields 
// this is a comment, if the line starts with  //
// and blank lines as well then ignore them

A, Sanford, Manchester

B ,  Huddersfield, Oxford

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(dataFile).useDelimiter(("\\s*,\\s*"));

while(scanner.hasNext() &&(!(line = scanner.nextLine()).startsWith("\\")))
        {

            String lines= scanner.nextLine();

        }
```

Comment: Your // and \\ are inconsistent. Please edit your question

Answer (score 3):

`Scanner s = new Scanner(dataFile).useDelimiter("\\s*,\\s*");`

This line will use commas as well as whitespace surrounding the comma as the delimiter. So if your data looks like:

> A, Sanford, Manchester
>
> B , Huddersfield, Oxford

```
while (s.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(s.next());
}
```

Then the above should output:

```
A  
Sanford 
Manchester 
B    
Huddersfield     
Oxford
```

Comment: okay but what about ignoring spaces at the beaning of the line

Comment: Another way to do this is to call the trim() method on each token after you retrieve it. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()

Comment: Nevermind that, the Scanner now matches leading/trailing whitespace. See the OR condition in the pattern.

Comment: You shouldn't paste code without surrounding it with code tags, i.e. backticks :-) `my code here`

Comment: `(!(line = scanner.nextLine()).startsWith("//") || !(line = scanner.nextLine()).startsWith(" "))`

Comment: If you want your **output** to **ignore leading whitespace** (spaces at the beginning of the line), you can use the delimiter in my answer. But if you want to **keep** any **leading whitespace** as part of your **output**, you should remove the OR condition from the delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

...

```
String lines= scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println(lines.trim()+"\n");
```

String lines= scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(lines+"\n");

Comment: Okay how to ignore black at the begning of the line